# Why is the YUIJsCompressorProcessor class not included in either the core or extensions jars for wro4j?

Tags: java, grails, yui, minify, wro4j

I would like to incorporate wro4j into my grails project.  I have everything setup, but I'm getting a JSMin UnterminatedStringLiteralException when the minifier attempts to compress the OpenLayers.js file I'm using.

So I figured it would be worth the time to configure wro4j to use a different js minification tool.  After reading through the documentation on the wro4j wiki, I added the core and extension jar to my project.

The problem is that neither jar contains the class file for the YUIJsCompressorProcessor despite the [documentation indicating otherwise](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/AvailableProcessors). So I need to know whether or not there is something I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YUIJsCompressorProcessor was deprecated and removed since version 1.6.0, because the library is not developed anymore and uses an older version of rhino, which is not compatible with other processors requiring newer version of rhino.

As an alternative, you can use GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor, UglifyJsProcessor or PackerJsProcessor.